# SQL how to get the min timestamp including null / empty data (db2)

Tags: sql, db2

Table 2

```
ID  DATE
--  ----------
01  2018-04-01
03  2017-06-23
```

I am having hard time trying to write a SQL that will return the ID that has no date or minimum date based on the IDs

for example, for ID 01, 03 only,
the sql should return 03 because between 01 and 03, 03 has the earlier date.

but for ID 01,02,03 only,
the sql should return 02 because 02 has no data.

for all IDs, 01,02,03,04
the sql can return either 02 or 04.

I've been playing around with MIN(DATE) and NOT EXISTS clauses but no luck because I do not know how to return the empty data.

Any sample SQL is greatly appreciated!

SQL I tried

```
SELECT MIN(CASE WHEN DATE IS NULL THEN '1900-01-01' ELSE DATE END)
FROM TABLE2
WHERE ID IN (01,02,03,04)
```

but above sql will give me the min of existing dates.  won't default non existing date to 1900-01-01.

Comment: use isnull(date, '1900-01-01') - this will default any nulls to 1900-01-01

Comment: DB2, it's NVL(date, '1900-01-01') but it still returns null, not the default value, so your suggestion didn't work

Comment: see my full answer below

Answer (score 1):

use left outer join:

select t1.name, t2.date from Table1 t1
left join Table 2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id

then use isnull on t2.date to stick anything you want in that field.

Comment: Thanks, LEFT JOIN did help!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the values that you want to check is listed in table 1

```
SELECT MIN(CASE WHEN table2.DATE IS NULL THEN '1900-01-01' ELSE table2.DATE END) as output
FROM TABLE1
left join TABLE2
  on table1.ID = table2.ID
```

Comment: Thanks, LEFT JOIN did help!

Answer (score 1):

Use full join in case there are values that don't match in either table

```
select a.id, a.name, min(isnull(b.date, '1900-01-01')) mindate from #table1 a 
full join  #table2 b on a.id=b.id  
group by a.id, a.name
```

Comment: Thank you.  It's not quite what I'm looking for but you gave me a direction.

Comment: OK good - how can I help further? What exactly is still incorrect?

Comment: I realized that I do not even need the table 1.  so I edited the question but many people already answered using table 1.

Comment: OK I see- so just apply the same logic without the join then

Comment: Thank, but must be db2 thing.  it still returns empty rows.

Comment: I +1 your answer since I got to the point where I was able to make the workaround.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this? Good luck!

`SELECT
  t1.id
FROM
  t1
LEFT JOIN 
  t2
ON
  t2.id = t1.id
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT
  MIN(COALESCE(date, DATE('2000-01-01'))) AS minimum_date
  FROM
  t2
) minimum_date
ON
  minimum_date = COALESCE(t2.date, DATE('2000-01-01'))
;`

Comment: Thanks, LEFT JOIN did help!

Comment: @AlisonAftra - Please accept this as the answer, if this resolved your question.  It looked like it did.